# Accessing a value from another model in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-15

I have 2 simple models:

the first one is to create a product total

the other one is to calculate product total.

I want to get the product total value from the second model and pass first model how can I do that?
**I want to get ans fields value from second model ans pass total field from first model**

```
class MyinvoiceInvoice(models.Model):
   _name = "myinvoice.invoice"
  total = fields.Integer(string="Total",store=True)

class InvoiceLine(models.Model):
    _name = "myinvoice.invoice.line"
    _description = "myinvoice.invoice.line"
    _inherit = "myinvoice.invoice"
    
    customer_id = fields.Many2one('myinvoice.invoice', string='Customer Id')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('myinvoice.product', string='Product')
    quanitity = fields.Integer(string="Quanitity")
    unit_price = fields.Integer(string="Unit Price",related='product_id.price')
    line_total = fields.Integer(string="Line Total",compute='_compute_total')
    ans = fields.Integer(string='ans')

   @api.depends('quanitity')
    def _compute_total(self):
        check = 0
        for record in self:
             if record.quanitity:
                record.line_total = record.unit_price * record.quanitity
                check += record.line_total
              else:
                record.quanitity = 0
        record.ans = check
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question accurately, but it seems that you are trying to get the **ans** field filled up based on whatever the **total** is. First of all find and get which field links both these model (in your case it is the customer_id field), probably there will be a Many2one relation between these two models. Using this related field (customer_id) you can user related fields to obtain the total into ans. It would be something like the following:

```
ans = fields.Integer(related=customer_id.total, string='ans')
```